# How to pass output from one pipeline to another in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins and I've been tasked with a simple task of passing the output from one pipeline to the other.

Lets say that the first pipeline has a script that says echo HelloWorld, how would i pass this output to another pipeline so it displays the same thing.

I've looked at parameterized triggers and couple of other answers but I was hoping if someone could layout the step by step procedure to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement it purely with Jenkins pipeline code - what I do is have an orchestrator pipeline job that builds all the pipeline jobs in my process, waits for them to complete then gets the build number:

**Orchestrator job**

```
def result = build job: 'jobA'
def buildNumber = result.getNumber()
echo "jobA build number : ${buildNumber}"
```

In each job like say '*jobA*' I arrange to write the output to a known file (a properties file for example) which is then archived:

**jobA**

```
writeFile encoding: 'utf-8', file: 'results.properties', text: 'a=123\r\nb=foo'

archiveArtifacts 'results.properties'
```

Then after the build of each job like *jobA*, use the build number and use the Copy Artifacts plugin to get the file back into your orchestrator job and process it however you want:

**Orchestrator job**

```
    step([$class     : 'CopyArtifact',
          filter     : 'results.properties',
          flatten    : true,
          projectName: 'jobA',
          selector   : [$class     : 'SpecificBuildSelector',
                        buildNumber: buildNumber.toString()]])
```

You will find these plugins useful to look at:

- [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)
- [Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md)

If you are chaining jobs instead of using an orchestrator - say jobA builds jobB builds jobC etc - then you can use a similar method. CopyArtifacts can copy from the upstream job or you can pass parameters with the build number and name of the upstream job. I chose to use an orchestrator job after changing from chained jobs because I need some jobs to be built in parallel.